# Remapify: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I try to get a simple basic example to work with [remapify](https://github.com/joeybaker/remapify). But if I run `node build.js` I always get `Cannot find module 'lib/lib.js'`

### files:

```
app.js
build.js
src/js/lib/lib.js
```

#### app.js

```
// instead of: require('./src/js/lib/lib.js');
require('lib/lib.js');
```

#### build.js

```
var browserify = require('browserify')
    , remapify = require('remapify')
    , b = browserify()

b.add('./app.js');

b.plugin(remapify, [
    {
        src: './src/js/lib/**.js',
        expose: 'lib',
        cwd: __dirname
    }
]);

b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly found a solution: I had to change the mapping option to:

```
{
    src: '**/*.js',
    expose: 'lib',
    cwd: './src/js/lib'
}
```